# How to output the original code in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I work on component library and want to have a tree shaking and full control on produced code so I want to have component to output the original code while running & testing component with typescript in component's sandbox.

Setting `"target": "esnext",` does not help - typescript transpiles the code not into es5 but modifies original code.

How to set up typescript to output original code?

Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "composite": true,
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "react",

        "importHelpers": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "lib"]
}
```

Here is my [Github repo](https://github.com/budarin/ui-kit-bootstrap)

Comment: What do you mean by "output the original code"? If you want the pure typescript, just output that. If you want to purely remove the type annotations, then continue as you are.

Comment: You're probably asking the wrong question here. I think you just want to change `"module": "commonjs"` to `"module": "ES2015"` so that it maintains import and export declarations.

Comment: @DavidSherret if I set  `ES2015` - typescript throws error on import: `node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:29:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'csstype'.

29 import * as CSS from 'csstype';`

Comment: I've added link to my GitHub repo